# httpErrors shows 500 error instead of YSOD on local machine

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, webforms, ysod

I am using `httpErrors` in my sites web.config to handle 404 errors. This was not working correctly until I added `existingResponse="Replace"` to the node but now I dont get any yellow screen of death errors on my local development machine.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" >
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.aspx?c=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
 </httpErrors>
```

Comment: Anyone want to try this and tell me if they get the same issue when there is an exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing the `existingResponse` value to `Auto`.  That worked for me.  I'm now able to use a custom 404 page, while also seeing the yellow screen of death errors.

Comment: Thanks mate! NB when setting http errors through IIS it is set to "Replace" for you

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `errorMode` attribute to `DetailedLocalOnly`. This will allow you to see YSOD on local environment and httpErrors when accessing your website from remote machine